# How to show value properly in an Input through NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

So i am a novice in NodeJS, i am working on a project, and when i return the value, it is not showing properly in HTML.

[image]

When i clicked on the "compressed" button, it calculate in NodeJS and send it back to my HTML files, but you can see the result is showing just under  the input, what can i do so the value is show inside ?

HTML code :

```
    <input id="compressedDigitalLink" class="compressedDigitalLink" type="text" v-model="compressedDigitalLink"> {{compressedDigitalLink}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg  " id="input_text" placeholder="Mettre le lien ici">{{compressedDigitalLink}}
```

Thank you

Comment: Put your data in `value` of `input`

Comment: This is basic HTML. Node.js is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `value` attribute of the `input` element:

```
<input id="compressedDigitalLink" class="compressedDigitalLink" type="text" v-model="compressedDigitalLink" value="{{compressedDigitalLink}}" />
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg  " id="input_text" placeholder="Mettre le lien ici" value="{{compressedDigitalLink}}" />
```

Comment: I did it, but it is not showing, I add the value attribute like you said, but it's not working, i have an empty input